# how to plot many categories with matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider the example below

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'type' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q'],
                   'value' : [2,3,4,2,5,3,6,5,3,1,3,5,7,5,3,5,4],
                   'date' : [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')]*17})

dfa
Out[337]: 
   type  value       date
0   a    2     2021-01-01
1   b    3     2021-01-01
2   c    4     2021-01-01
3   d    2     2021-01-01
4   e    5     2021-01-01
5   f    3     2021-01-01
6   g    6     2021-01-01
7   h    5     2021-01-01
8   i    3     2021-01-01
9   j    1     2021-01-01
10  k    3     2021-01-01
11  l    5     2021-01-01
12  m    7     2021-01-01
13  n    5     2021-01-01
14  o    3     2021-01-01
15  p    5     2021-01-01
16  q    4     2021-01-01
```

As you can see, I have (too) many categories but I still need to plot all of them at the same time. I tried to use the `hatch` argument in `matplotlib` but this does not seem to shade some patterns and not the others (so that more categories are visually distinct).

```
dfa.set_index(['date','type']).unstack().plot.bar(stacked = True, hatch = 'o')
```

[image]

What can I do here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the generated bars, and assign a unique [hatch pattern](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_style_reference.html) to each individual group. You'll need to generate the legend again, so it gets updated with the changed bars.

Choosing `bar.set_hatch(pattern * 2)` instead of just `bar.set_hatch(pattern)` will generate a pattern that is twice as dense. See the [hatch demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_demo.html) for more examples.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'] * 2,
                    'value': [2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 4,
                              3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3],
                    'date': [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')] * 17 + [pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')] * 17})
ax = dfa.set_index(['date', 'type']).unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)
hatch_patterns = ['/', '\\', '|', '-', '+', 'x', 'o', 'O', '.', '*', '/o', '\\|', '|*', '-\\', '+o', 'x*', 'o-', 'O|']
for bars, pattern in zip(ax.containers, hatch_patterns):
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_hatch(pattern * 2)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.01), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: stack bar plot with individual hatching]

Comment: really cool! thanks! can you just explain what that `ax.containers` are and why do multiply patterns time 2?

Comment: `ax.containers` is where matplotlib stores the groups of bars that were previously created.  Multiplying a hatch pattern makes it more dense (multiplying a string is similar to repeating it, so `'x'*2`is `'xx'` and is twice as dense as `'x'`).